# MongoDB/Mongoose: Query for valid document property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose for MongoDB I store several collections of data which are defined each by a Mongoose schema.

1) Is there an easy way (without explicitly querying the database) to find out whether a specific property is part of a particular collection schema model?

Lets say I have a collection of users, including information about name and address. At runtime I - for mistake - receive data which is supposed to be stored in the user's document but does not (fully) comply with the schema (e. g. shoe size is included).

2) I know that Mongoose refuses to save the data set in that case but how and at all do I get some sort of feedback about that to report back appropriately to the client?

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way to check whether a certain collection contains documents that have the field that you mention is to run a count query with the `$exists` operator on each collection:

```
db.collection1.count({ field: { $exists: true }});
db.collection2.count({ field: { $exists: true }});
db.collection3.count({ field: { $exists: true }});
```

Afterwards, you can save the return value of each `count` operation in a variable and pass it to the client, thus making it possible to convey a message to the end-user.